# how to get last inserted identity value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to select last inserted row identity value so i tried below code

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() from tb_new_product_Name_id
```

but its not showing. where i made error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three similar concepts in MS SQL Server - @@IDETITy, SCOPE_IDENTITY() and IDENT_CURRENT().

Here are sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE TestData (
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL)
INSERT TestData VALUES('one'), ('two')


CREATE TABLE TrigData (
id INT IDENTITY(100,5) PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20) NULL)
INSERT TrigData(name)
VALUES('one'), ('two'), ('three')

CREATE TRIGGER Ztrig
ON TestData
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
INSERT TrigData VALUES('from trig')
END

INSERT TestData VALUES('dummy')

SELECT @@IDENTITY AS [@@IDENTITY]
GO
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY]
GO
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TestData') [IDENT_CURRENT]
```

It returns 115, 3 and 3.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify a table name here..
SCOPE_IDENTITY() is just a function which returns the recent identity value generated in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
/* Variable */
DECLARE @NewDocumentID int;
/* Insert record statement here. In my case table name is document.*/
INSERT INTO document (name) VALUES ('TEMP');
SELECT @NewDocumentID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
PRINT @NewDocumentID
```